# format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }

Tags: ruby-on-rails

what is the use of

```
 format.json { render json: @product, status: :created, location: @product }
 format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
```

in the following code of the controller Product

```
def create
@product = Product.new(params[:product])

respond_to do |format|
  if @product.save
    format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @product, status: :created, location: @product }

  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

Comment: What do you mean by `function`?Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

It renders a json response if json is requested, the same way it does with html if html is requested. If you load it in a browser, it is going to give you html, but you may want yo get the json if you are doing something with it. You should use "what is the use of" and not "function", which is ambiguous.

Comment: location:@product  is a redirect  in JSON?

Comment: Sorry, my fault, it is ruby code but referring to json, it takes the product var and rails understands you mean the product url. @user3678471 dont worry about that if youre not going to use json. You can even delete it

Comment: In html after of create the product rails goes to the show action to display the product in screen

Comment: Yes, is that a question?

Comment: the same thing happens in JSON with location: @product

Comment: Juan can speak Spanish here?

Comment: Yes i do and can, tell me

Comment: render json: @ product, is the JSON representation of the object created 
status :: created is the http response 
location: @ product is a link to the show action

Comment: That means render product in json, the status is created and http response location is @product, which rails identifies automatically as the product location